# firebase cloud messaging target segments not actived

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification to some particular segments but some items are disabled.I implemented firebase in unity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that we should give permission to Share Analytics data with all Firebase features,(project setting>>data privacy)